# Build a dynamic custom annotation for which I can inject value from application.properties in spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, annotations, spring-data-mongodb

I want to build a custom annotation on top of Meta (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Meta.html) where I can dynamically inject cursorBatchSize from application.properties.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Meta;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Meta(cursorBatchSize = 100)
public @interface DynamicMeta {
    @AliasFor(annotation = Meta.class, attribute = "cursorBatchSize")
    @Value("#{${dynamic.cursor.batch.size:100}}")
    int cursorBatchSize() default 100;
}
```

But with the above code, on using the annotation, I always find the value getting used is default value itself, though the property was present inside the application.properties.

Comment: You cannot set values like that in an annotation, simply becaue annotation values need to be static. If you want dynamic behavior you should implement that in the processor of said annotation. Also you shouldn't set the value in the `@Meta` annotation in this case as you define an alias.

Comment: Can you help me with an example of processor ?

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer with example. Would love to learn.

Comment: In this case you cannot provide a processor as it is a merged/synthetic annotation and the real one being used is `@Meta`.

Comment: How do we build yet another Meta like annotation, which could be used for dynamic cursorBatch attribute and use it with a processor ?

Comment: You would need to extend/re-implement parts of Spring Data for that and write your own annotation which would allow a String as a value so you could parse/handle it.